# What happens to the retired night guards?

Tags: plot-explanation, night-at-the-museum

In *Night At The Museum*, Ben Stiller is hired as a replacement for three retiring night guards who soon return to rob the museum at which they had worked. With the help of the magically animated exhibits, Stiller captures the three and ties them up. They are never mentioned again.

What happens to the three guards?

Comment: May be they got arrested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Cecil, Gus, and Reginald are forced to become museum janitors to evade
>   being sent to jail for their crimes. -  (Source :[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_at_the_Museum))

And from [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0477347/faq#.2.1.18)

> In some versions, Cecil, Gus, and Reginald were forced to clean up the
>   lobby, seen in the end credits. 'We're nightwatchmen, not janitors!'
>   says Gus during these end credits.)